# Failed to remove – ' ' despite using re from text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I tried remove – and  ' ' from the next but I am unable to remove.

My coding is as follows:

```
import re

with open('NoSpace.text') as f1:
    with open('NoSymbol.text', 'w')as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for  line in lines:

        str = line
        regex = re.compile('[,\.!?@#=*^()-:""'']')
        m = regex.sub('', str)
                f2.write(m)


f2.close()
print('All symbols are removed')
```

Below is a sample of the text:

```
Physical geography – examines the natural environment and how the climate, vegetation & life, soil, water, and landforms are produced and interact.
==== Fields of physical geography ====

Glaciology – study of glaciers, or more generally ice and natural phenomena that involve ice.

Biogeography – study of the distribution of species spatially and temporally'refugium'.
```

The result after running the script:

```
Glaciology – study of glaciers or more generally ice and natural phenomena that involve ice

Biogeography – study of the distribution of species spatially and temporally'refugium'
```

**Problem**

Noticed from the processed text some of the symbols are still retained like  – and ' '

From my coding I added: `regex = re.compile('[,\.!?@#=*^()-:""'']')` yet it still fail to remove it.

When I tried adding this symbol " – " into `regex = re.compile('[,\.!?@#=*^()-:–""'']')` it gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file SymbolRemove.py on line 9, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Is there a work around or a solution for my problem please?

This is what I want:

```
Glaciology  study of glaciers or more generally ice and natural phenomena that involve ice

Biogeography  study of the distribution of species spatially and temporally refugium
```

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to do? Question should be like this is the script i have this is the input, This is what i get as output, but this is what i want.

Comment: Did you try to set an encoding for the file? Put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first or second line of the script and make sure that it is saved with an UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Hi, Matthias I tried the putting in # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, it didnt work , it removed all my content.

Comment: Just do `someString.replace('-', '').replace("'", '')` – no need to use regular expressions here.

Comment: Hi poke, I'm new to python, may i have a more detailed example please? Is it possible to modify my coding please? Thank you

Comment: It looks like what you have is not a hyphen `-` but rather a [emdash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm); which is probably why your regular expressions are not working.

Comment: Hi Burhan do you happen to know how to remove the emdash?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's an en dash (U+2013) not em dash ([U+2014](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)).  The "em" signifies the width of the lowercase letter "m" and the "en" similarly a dash with the same width as the lowercase letter "n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash in your text is an en dash ([U+2013](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm); a Unicode character), not the ASCII minus sign.

In addition to that, there are some mistakes in your code.

In a character class (inside of `[...]` in a regex) a dash denotes a range. So `)-:` in your regex specifies a range.  This is not what you want.

In Python, you can use a backslash to specify a literal dash; more generally, the portable solution is to put the dash first or last, where it cannot denote a range.

```
regex = re.compile('[,.!?@#=*^()\-:""\']')
```

or

```
regex = re.compile('[-,.!?@#=*^():""\']')
```

(Inside a character class, `.` does not need to be escaped, so I took that out. The single quote obviously does need escaping.)

The character class `[)-:]` covers the following characters:

```
>>> ''.join([chr(x) for x in range(ord(')'), ord(':'))])
')*+,-./0123456789'
```

Finally, you should not use the name of the built-in type `str` as an identifier, you don't need to (or even cannot) `close` stuff you opened in `with`, recompiling the regex on each iteration is extremely wasteful; and reading the input file line by line is much more efficient than reading it all into memory and then iterating over a huge buffer.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

# Note use of Unicode string, and addition of en dash as second member
regex = re.compile(u'[-–,.!?@#=*^():""\']')
with open('NoSpace.text') as f1, open('NoSymbol.text', 'w')as f2:
    for line in f1:
        m = regex.sub('', line)
        f2.write(m)
print('All symbols are removed')
```

Comment: I seem to have mistyped something while editing.  Sorry about that.  Should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the en dash is still not working:( Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: It works for me, on Unicode strings.  Maybe your file has a different encoding.  We can't really tell without lots more detail.  See the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for some troubleshooting help; maybe post a separate question if you cannot figure it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.